# How to read a file in which a column was messed up?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a "\t" separated data file looks like this:

```
Hotel       Price   Location
hotel1      100       A
hotel2      Unknown   B
hotel3      1,200     C
hotel4      <id=?h    B
```

In the column "Price", some numbers contain comma and look like "1,200". The column "Price" of some rows are messed up and contain "Unknown" or something else with no "\t" and no specific pattern.

How can I read this file, delete all rows with messed up "Price", and delete all commas in numbers? What I want to get is the following:

```
Hotel       Price   Location
hotel1      100     A
hotel3      1200    C
```

I've tried using

```
price <- read.table("hotel.txt", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("Price"="integer"))
```

It's not working because scan() expected 'an integer' but got something not integer.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2 steps:

```
## remove not numeric like Price
dat <- dat[grepl('[0-9]+',dat$Price),]
# Hotel Price Location
# 1 hotel1   100        A
# 3 hotel3 1,200        C

## convert price to numeric
dat$Price <- as.numeric(gsub(',','',dat$Price))

 Hotel Price Location
1 hotel1   100        A
3 hotel3  1200        C
```

where dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text='Hotel   Price   Location
hotel1  100 A
hotel2  Unknown B
hotel3  1,200   C
hotel4  <id=?h  B',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I do want to up-vote your answer.. But I don't have enough reputation, sorry for that..